# Easiest way to parse file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, text-parsing

I'm trying to extract contour points from a text file with MATLAB. An example of a line that contains those contour points is:

```
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/146/171/5/146.912065/171.618881/5.500000/0
```

Note that not every line starts with the string Cnt-0-Pt (as there are other fields besides contour points in these files), but every contour point line always has a 0 in its field string, that is, there is not the option that a contour point line will start with Cnt-1-Pt, for example. After that string, there is a space and two tabs. I want to extract the three integers that are after the second / delimiter. In this example, they would be 146, 171, and 5. What would be the most straightforward way to do this?

Here is an example of how the text file looks like

```
#
# Direction U 
#
U-Number        92
U-Scale         1.470000
#
# Direction V 
#
V-Number        204
V-Scale         1.470000
#
# Direction W 
#
W-Number        16
W-Scale         1.470000
s-base-plane        0
#
#  Video/Recorder Parameters
#
play-mode        toggle
rotate-mode         ObjAxis
d-xrotate       0.000
d-yrotate       0.000
d-zrotate       0.000
#
#  Cut-Oblique Parameters
#
Plane-size      1.470
Plane-2D        off
Plane-3D        off
#
#  ValidVol Parameters
#
validity-field      ignored
#
#  Histogram Parameters
#
histo-scale         1.000000
#
#  VOI Parameters
#
Margin-Mode         2
#
#  VOI Segmentations
#
Slice-Dist-U        0.562500
Slice-Dist-V        0.562500
Slice-Dist-W        3.000000
MVol_Volume         0
#Contour 0 Parameter 
Contour-Start    0
Cnt-0-Contour-name      Prostate
Cnt-0-Contour-color-list        16711680
Cnt-0-Contour-color         16711680
Cnt-0-Contour-Type      0
Cnt-0-Contour-Class         0
Cnt-0-Contour-Mandatory         1
Cnt-0-Contour-num       19
Cnt-0-Inter-Contour-color       12517376
Cnt-0-Segmentation_U        No
Cnt-0-Segmentation_V        No
Cnt-0-Segmentation_W        Yes
Cnt-0-Cnt       919.658969/118.184765/919.658969/118.184765/5
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/146/171/5/146.912065/171.618881/5.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/148/154/5/148.514670/154.791536/5.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/153/146/5/153.055382/146.511414/5.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/165/139/5/165.876216/139.299695/5.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/178/140/5/178.429949/140.635199/5.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/188/143/5/188.045574/143.306206/5.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/195/152/5/195.524394/152.921831/5.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/203/164/5/203.804516/164.140061/5.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/206/178/5/206.475523/178.563499/5.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/206/191/5/206.475523/191.384333/5.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/204/201/5/204.338717/201.267059/5.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/199/208/5/199.530904/208.745879/5.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/193/213/5/193.387588/213.553691/5.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/186/213/5/186.175869/213.820792/5.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/180/206/5/180.833855/206.876174/5.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/176/198/5/176.026042/198.061851/5.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/169/189/5/169.348525/189.514628/5.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/162/182/5/162.671007/182.570010/5.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/152/177/5/152.254080/177.495096/5.500000/0
Cnt-0-Cnt       1210.414404/141.990846/1210.414404/141.990846/6
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/173/139/6/173.622136/139.833897/6.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/181/131/6/181.368056/131.286674/6.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/197/129/6/197.126998/129.951171/6.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/207/142/6/207.009724/142.772005/6.500000/0
Cnt-0-Pt        0/0/214/153/6/214.221443/153.990234/6.500000/0
```

Comment: please post a minimal, but complete example on how this file might look like. what is a "field string"?

Comment: "not every line" I see only one line.

Comment: Sorry, I should have put a complete example. It's there now

Comment: Is the part above the first `'Cnt-0-Pt'` always the same number of lines or does it vary?

Comment: It's variable. And the number of 'Cnt-0-Pt' lines also varies

Comment: Is there always a single `'Cnt-0-Cnt'` line right before the `'Cnt-0-Pt'` lines begin?

Comment: Yes, there is. And there is more than one of those 'Cnt-0-Cnt' lines. I updated the example again to exemplify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you effectively have a non-trivial, variable line header and different elements mixed in with your data of interest. Normally a file like this would need to be parsed line-by-line (the file format should probably have used an XML structure), but it may be possible to use the fast [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html).

The first step is to find the point in the file where the `'Cnt-0-Pt'` lines begin. The code below gets one line at a time using [`fgetl`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) until it finds the `'Cnt-0-Cnt'` line. Then `textscan` is used to read the rest of the file and save the relevant three columns into a cell array.

```
fid = fopen('test.txt');
while ~strncmp(fgetl(fid),'Cnt-0-Cnt',9)
end
C = textscan(fid,'%*s%*f/%*f/%f/%f/%f/%*s','CommentStyle','Cnt-0-Cnt')
fclose(fid);
```

The `textscan` format string, `'%*s%*f/%*f/%f/%f/%f/%*s'` ignores the first string, the first two numbers, and everything after the three number you're interested in. The `'CommentStyle'` is used as a sort of trick to ignore any subsequent lines that begin with `'Cnt-0-Cnt'`. See the `textscan` documentation for more complete details. It might be possible to avoid the `while` loop by adding all of the field names to a `'CommentStyle'` cell array, e.g., `{'#','U-Number','U-Scale','V-Number',...}`.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

A less clever, marginally more explicit version of @horchler's answer:

```
fID = fopen('test.txt', 'r');

ii = 1;
mydata = [];
while ~feof(fID) % Loop until we've reached the end of the file
    tline = fgetl(fID);
    if ~isempty(regexp(tline, 'Cnt-0-Pt', 'Once'))
        % Matched the line we want, parse it
        splitline = regexp(tline, '/', 'split'); % Split along the / delimiter
        tdata = cellfun(@str2double, splitline(3:5), 'UniformOutput', false); % Convert the strings you want to doubles
        mydata(ii,:) = [tdata{:}]; % Pull data out of the cell array
        ii = ii + 1;
    end
end

fclose(fID);
```

This goes through your file line-by-line until it reaches the end. If it finds your `Cnt-0-Pt` string, it parses the line for your data, otherwise the line is discarded.

This can be a very computationally intensive method to use since it doesn't play to any of MATLAB's strengths. Since the size and layout of your data is variable you can't preallocate or tell MATLAB where specifically in the file to read. Though in this situation the line-by-line approach may be the only good option.